# Как правильно прочитать файл?

Tags: c#

Всем привет! У меня есть обычный текстовый файл, в котором каждый новый элемент - это новая строка. Пример файла:

```
Игра 
Строитель 
Лампа
Стол
```

И вот мне надо загрузить это всё в listBox, чтобы каждая строка в файле была отдельной строкой в listBox'e. Когда я делаю так:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open("history.txt", FileMode.Open)))
{
    listHistory.Items.Add(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

У меня всё в одной строке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если "каждый новый элемент это новая строка", т.е. файл выглядит так:

```
Игра
Строитель
Лампа
Стол
```

тогда можно решить так:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open("history.txt", FileMode.Open)))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    listHistory.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вот это и помогло(второй вариант)

Answer (score 2):

StreamReader.ReadToEnd() считывает до конца файла в одну строку. Используйте StreamReader.ReadLine().

Answer (score 2):

Есть один недостаток в варианте

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open("history.txt", FileMode.Open)))  
            {  
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                listHistory.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }
```

Нам приходится много раз вызывать файл. А это достаточно длительный процесс
Логичнее прочитать весь файл sr.ReadToEnd();
А затем разбивать файл на части в самом коде
Примерно так

```
string[] strings;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"path.txt"))
        {
            strings = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
        }
```

Если я ошибаюсь - попросил бы исправить.
Код сверху - сжатый вариант этого кода

```
string[] strings;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"path.txt"))
        {
            string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
            char[] divizorz = new char[] { '\n' };
            strings = s.Split(divizorz);
        }
```

Просто по-моему сверху лучше, т.к. код не загромождается лишними именами
Здесь \n это означает символ переноса строки